# want to get user data on the behalf of manager id in batches table

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

i want to get user data from users table using eloquent with condition `where('role', 'user')` which enrolled with batches where manger id match with auth id

```
public function viewAllUserForManager()
    {

        if(Auth::check())

        {
        $orders[] = Batch::where('manager_id', Auth::User()->id)->pluck('id')->toArray();
        //dd($orders);
        foreach($orders as $order)
        {
            $orderProduct = OrderProduct::where('batch_id', $order)->pluck('user_id');
            //dd($orderProduct);
            if(!empty($orderProduct))
            {
                //dd($orderProduct);
                foreach($orderProduct as $product)
                {
                    dd($orderProduct);
                   $user[] = User::where('id', '=', $product)->where('role', 'user')->get();
                
                }
            }

        }
        
        $users = array_unique($user);
        //dd($users);       
        return view('manager.user.index', compact('users'));
    }
    return Redirect::route('login')->withInput()->with('delete', trans('flash.PleaseLogin')); 
    }
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you need / want

Comment: I personally don't understand your question. I think it's unclear what you want to achieve.

Comment: What is your question? ("_i want to..._" is _not_ a question) Does something not work? Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.